# Domain A record on active directory controller

Tags: linux, active-directory, a-record

Currently we have an Active Directory setup for a small network running on Debian 8 and Samba 4. At one point we had to change the ip address of the AD server from 100.0.0.4 to 100.0.0.100. I edited:

```
/etc/network/interfaces    
/etc/hosts
/etc/resolv.conf
```

The problem is that host -t A returns the old ip address.

```
root@serverdc:~# host -t A serverdc.domain.local
serverdc.domain.local has address 100.0.0.4
```

It looks like the server is running fine, but I dont want to leave it like this. 
I know that is a noob question but I can't find the answer, is there a way to modify this record ?

**UPDATE**

/etc/network/interfaces

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 100.0.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 100.0.0.1
    broadcast 100.0.0.255
    gateway 100.0.0.1
    dns-nameservers 100.0.0.100
    dns-search serverdc.local
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
100.0.0.100     serverdc.domain.local   serverdc
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
search serverdc.domain.local
nameserver 100.0.0.100
```

nslookup

```
root@serverdc:~# nslookup serverdc.domain.local
Server:         100.0.0.100
Address:        100.0.0.100#53
Name:   serverdc.domain.local
Address: 100.0.0.4
```

/etc/samba/smb.conf

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    workgroup = DOMAIN
    realm = DOMAIN.LOCAL
    netbios name = SERVERDC
    server role = active directory domain controller
    dns forwarder = 100.0.0.1
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

    idmap config * : range = 10000 - 20000
    map untrusted to domain = Yes
    winbind enum users = Yes
    winbind enum groups = Yes
    winbind use default domain = Yes

[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/altfel.local/scripts
    read only = No
    browsable = No

[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No
    browsable = No

# After this line are the samba shares
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly and I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but I would check the following:

Make sure that the DNS server ist set up correctly and check if the DNS server resolves serverdc.domain.local to 100.0.0.100. Use nslookup or dig to check the resolution.
Did you restart the networking service on your Debian machine?

If that's not the answer to your problem yet, you may post your changes to the files you described, that may help others to answer your question.

It would also help that you describe your network setup more in detail.

Hope this helps.

***Edit (final solution):***

So finally the OP used samba as DNS server and an update to the existing A record was required, which is done by:

```
samba-tool dns update 100.0.0.100 domain.local serverdc A 100.0.0.4 100.0.0.100
```

Comment: Would you please post the contents of the files /etc/hosts, /etc/network/interfaces, /etc/resolv.conf. Thanks

Comment: I updated the post with /etc/hosts, /etc/network/interfaces, /etc/resolv.conf. The server was restarted several times. In the network there are 20 computers a router (100.0.0.1) and the AD Server also used as a file server. The domain is local.

Comment: Looks to me like your DNS-Server still believes that this host has the IP address 100.0.0.4. Check the zone file of your dns namespace if the A record is correct.

Comment: I think here is my problem. I cant find the zone files. From google it looks like there are in /etc/bind/zones but I didn't installed bind.

Comment: So what kind of dns server are you using? If you are not sure use netstat -tulpn and look for port 53.

Comment: I guess that Samba is now managing the DNS. I used https://jimshaver.net/2014/07/13/setting-up-an-active-directory-domain-controller-using-samba-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/ to install the server.

Comment: Could you please post the contents of /etc/samba/smb.conf

Comment: Post updated with /etc/samba/smb.conf

Comment: Try this:

samba-tool dns update 100.0.0.100 serverdc.domain.local serverdc.domain.local A 100.0.0.100

Comment: Not working. Usage: samba-tool dns update <server> <zone> <name> <A|AAAA|PTR|CNAME|NS|MX|SOA|SRV|TXT> <olddata> <newdata>

Comment: There you got the answer so you have to edit it:samba-tool dns update 100.0.0.100 domain.local serverdc A 100.0.0.4 100.0.0.100